# Область влияния переменных в c#?

Tags: c#

Я немного запутался, вот есть два куска кода, в котором в одном из них поле помечено модификатором `static`  -значит оно глобальное и объявлено вне метода, как и положено

```
class Program
{
    static int x=1;
    static void Main()
    {
```

а в другом случае - поле просто объявлено вне метода без модификатора `static`

```
class Program
{
     int x;
    static void Main()
    {
```

- влияет ли это на что либо и будет ли она считаться глобальной? Знаю, вопрос Дурацкий, но я просто запутался в областях видимости(влияния переменных).

Comment: в обоих случаях `x` - это не переменная, а поле класса.

Comment: Но оно в обоих случаях глобальное или только в случае со static?

Comment: что значит глобальное? :-)

Comment: Доступная  в пределах всей программы а не только данного  -  класса/метода

Comment: К ней можно обратиться например из другого класса - это подразумевает, что она глобальная

Comment: нет, оба поля в данном случае не глобальные

Comment: @Grundy *в обоих случаях `x` - это не переменная, а поле класса.* Спецификация C# говорит, что поля класса ([статические](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md#static-variables) или [нестатические](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md#instance-variables)) являются переменными.

Comment: @PetSerAl в `C#` особая терминология на сей счет. Переменные могут быть только в пределах видимости метода. В пределах видимости класса - поля, в пределах видимости программы - свойства.

Comment: @PetSerAl, [GitHub](https://github.com) вдруг стал штамповать спецификации по C#? И они точнее MSDN будут?

Comment: @PetSerAl, если уж ссылаться на спецификации C#, то лучше вот в такие места: [Поля (Руководство по программированию в C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173118.aspx) или сюда [Свойства, поля и методы классов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a67b72ea(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @DenisBubnov *GitHub вдруг стал штамповать спецификации по C#?* Нет, GitHub спецификации не штампует. Это просто хостинг площадка, которую использует Microsoft для вовлечения сообщества в процесс разработки. И совсем не *вдруг*. Уже не первый год как Microsoft публикует открытые исходные коды своих проектов на GitHub, а не на своём CodePlex. *И они точнее MSDN будут?* Они будут новее. Последняя спецификация опубликованная на MSDN относится к C# 5, а уже C# 7 вышел.

Comment: @DenisBubnov *если уж ссылаться на спецификации C#, то лучше вот в такие места* Я с Вами не согласен. Во первых, это не спецификация а руководство. Во вторых, устаревшее. По первой ссылке висит примечание *For the latest documentation on C#, visit the C# Guide on docs.microsoft.com.*, так что не похоже, что Microsoft намеренна обновлять MSDN. А по второй ссылке вообще *Обновлен: Ноябрь 2007*, а в английской версии *This documentation is archived and is not being maintained.*

Comment: @PetSerAl, да, проблема терминологии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` говорит о том, что некоторое поле принадлежит не одному экземпляру, а всему классу:

```
class ProgramA
{
  public static int x;
}

class ProgramB
{
  public int x;
}

int xFromProgramA = ProgramA.x;

ProgramB k = new ProgramB();
k.x = 10;

ProgramB j = new ProgramB();
j.x = 20;

k.x == j.x // => false
```

> Доступная в пределах всей программы а не только данного - класса

Вы, судя по всему, о модификаторах доступа: `public`/`private`/`protected`/`internal`. В вашем случае: нет, обе переменные `private` по умолчанию, а следовательно доступны только внутри экземпляра/класса.